# npm: cannot find module which exists in node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

Say JS application A imports several public npm modules. Say B is one such module.

```
// ./A/index.js
import B from B;
```

I go to ./node_modules/B and modify its source by adding a new dependency in B's package.json, say C, which I import inside B

```
// ./node_modules/B/index.js
import C from C;
```

Then I run npm install inside ./node_modules/B which creates another node_modules directory inside  ./node_modules/B

When I run A I get an error like

```
Error: Could not find module C imported from B
```

What am I doing wrong?
and what is the best way to test the changes of an existing public module before I wrap them up for a PR?

Answer (score 0):

You doing it right, probably module C doesn't exist, you have 2 ways, first is the way you do it now (installing inside node_modules), second: use `require.resolve`, check the samples below

#### Sample demo when installing in node_modules

*index.js*

```
import yn from 'yn'; // sample lib for detecting yes/no
console.log(yn('yes'));
```

Run below inside *./node_modules/yn/*

```
npm install ccount --save //sample lib for counting symbols
```

*./node_modules/yn/index.js*

```
//.. omitted
const ccount = require('ccount');
console.log(ccount('123', '1'));
//.. omitted
```

Result

```
❯ node ./index.js 
1
true
```

#### Sample demo when installing in current directory

*index.js*

```
import yn from 'yn'; // sample lib for detecting yes/no
console.log(yn('yes'));
```

Run below in root directory (where ./index.js is)

```
npm install ccount --save //sample lib for counting symbols
```

*./node_modules/yn/index.js*

```
//.. omitted
const ccount = require(require.resolve('ccount', {paths: ['../../node_modules/ccount']}));
console.log(ccount('123', '1'));
//.. omitted
```

Result

```
❯ node ./index.js 
1
true
```